# Angular 5 localize-router set route with country/lang code

Tags: angular, routes, localization, angular2-routing, url-routing

Here is my problem. I have to set up routing in Angular so that in URL there will be a country code and a language. for example

> https://example.com/**usa/en**

The tricky part is that this localization parts can change so I have a button to switch country and language so it will be **/gb/en** or **/usa/fr**.

How can I get it working like this using localize-router and ngx-translate.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Do you need this country/language code for each route or just as an entry point of your app ?

Comment: each route needs to have this combo. This is a requirement for SEO purposes - we are using Angular Universal server-side rendering.

Comment: You can use the router for this without using localize router. by adding root urls are like this route: [{path: ':country/:lang', children[ < YOUR OTHERS COMPONENTS GOES HERE />]}]

Comment: @PiotrSmyda: For your additional information, https://medium.com/frontend-fun/angular-introduction-to-internationalization-i18n-28226a85e04e

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pardon me if I got your question wrong, but if I understand it correctly you can follow below approach:

In your **AppRoutingModule** configure routes as below:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { 
     path:'' , pathMatch: 'full', component: SomeComponent,
     children: [
        { path: ':country-code/:lang-code' , component: SomeOtherComponent }
     ]
  }
]
```

You can now redirect by your button click event and it changes **country-code** and **lang-code** accordingly and you can retrieve these values in your **SomeOtherComponent** to perform related tasks.